# Example on webcrawling news headlines and contents in Python

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a beginner in WebCrawling, and I have a question regarding crawling multiple urls.

I am using CNBC in my project. I want to extract news titles and urls from its home page, and I also want to crawl the contents of the news articles from each url.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import requests
from lxml import html 
import pandas

url = "http://www.cnbc.com/"
response = requests.get(url) 
doc = html.fromstring(response.text)

headlineNode = doc.xpath('//div[@class="headline"]')
len(headlineNode)

result_list  = []
for node in headlineNode : 
    url_node = node.xpath('./a/@href')
    title = node.xpath('./a/text()')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_node.content)
    text =[''.join(s.findAll(text=True)) for s in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"group"})]
    if (url_node and title and text) : 
        result_list.append({'URL' : url + url_node[0].strip(),
                            'TITLE' : title[0].strip(),
                            'TEXT' : text[0].strip()})
print(result_list)
len(result_list)
```

I am keep on getting an error saying that'list' object has no attribute 'content'. I want to create a dictionary that contains titles for each headlines, urls for each headlines, and the news article content for each headlines. Is there an easier way to approach this?

Comment: But your url is a string containing cnbc's web address, so it isn't surprising that it doesn't have a .content property. Maybe you meant url_code.content?

Comment: @Bemmu still doesn't work, but I have edited the question!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some js that is protecting the content

Answer (score 3):

Great start on the script. However, `soup = BeautifulSoup(url_node.content)` is wrong. `url_content` is a list. You need to form the full news URL, use requests to get the HTML and then pass it to BeautifulSoup.

Apart from that, there are a few things I would look at:

1. I see import issues, BeautifulSoup is not imported.
   Add `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` to the top. Are you using pandas? If not, remove it.
2. Some of the news divs on CNN with the big banner picture will yield a 0 length list when you query `url_node = node.xpath('./a/@href')`. You need to find the appropriate logic and selectors to get those news URLs as well. I will leave that up to you.

Check this out:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Note trailing backslash removed
url = "http://www.cnbc.com"
response = requests.get(url)
doc = html.fromstring(response.text)

headlineNode = doc.xpath('//div[@class="headline"]')
print(len(headlineNode))

result_list  = []
for node in headlineNode:
    url_node = node.xpath('./a/@href')
    title = node.xpath('./a/text()')
    # Figure out logic to get that pic banner news URL
    if len(url_node) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        news_html = requests.get(url + url_node[0])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(news_html.content)
        text =[''.join(s.findAll(text=True)) for s in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"group"})]
        if (url_node and title and text) :
            result_list.append({'URL' : url + url_node[0].strip(),
                                'TITLE' : title[0].strip(),
                                'TEXT' : text[0].strip()})
print(result_list)
len(result_list)
```

Bonus debugging tip:

Fire up an ipython3 shell and do `%run -d yourfile.py`. Look up `ipdb` and the debugging commands. It's quite helpful to check what your variables are and if you're calling the right methods.

Good luck.